# COUNTIF for date is within the current week and for in the last week

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2013, countif

I am creating a refreshable spreadsheet which pulls activities from SQL queries.

On the first page I need a formula that counts all the occurrences of a contact method that falls in the current week and the count of all occurrences that fall in the previous week.

Here is what my data set looks like:

```
Contact Employee  Date              Method  
Jack    John      12/16/15          Email
Jack    John      12/7/15           Email
Jill    John      12/9/15           Call
Rick    Amber     12/8/15           Call
Dave    Sarah     12/10/15          Email
Dave    Sarah     12/15/15          Call
Dave    Sarah     12/9/15           Email
Don     Amber     12/14/15          Call
```

What I want is for the data to return like this:

```
TimeFrame      #ofCalls  #ofEmails
Current Week      2          1
Last Week         2          3
```

I want to use a formula that looks for dates that fall with the current week and counts the occurrence and then another formula that looks for dates that fall within the prior week and counts the occurrences in that week.

I'd like the formula to stay the same so if I refresh the sheet each day, I don't have to change the date range in the formula.

Comment: @pnuts excel 2013, sorry edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two methods.

Using formulas, and assuming the first day of the week is a Monday.

```
Current Week Start Date:  =TODAY()+1-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)
Last Week Start Date:     =CurrentWeekStart -7
```

Current Week Email (using a table and structured references)

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Date],">="&CurrentWeekStart,Table1[Date],"<"&CurrentWeekStart+7,Table1[Method],"Email")
```

Last Week Emails

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Date],">="&LastWeekStart,Table1[Date],"<" & CurrentWeekStart,Table1[Method],"Email")
```

For the Calls, just change "Email" to "Calls" in the above formulas.

A second method would be to use a Pivot Table

Drag Dates to Rows; Method to Columns; Method to Values; Group Dates by 7 
Days and ensure first date is on the start date of a week; Format to taste.

Use filters if you only want to see two weeks.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! thank you! for the last week end date, wouldn't it be (TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())-0)?

Comment: @FBeveridge You're welcome.  Your formula in your comment returns a Saturday.  In my Answer, I stated that Monday would be the start of the week.  So if you want Sunday to be the week start day, you'd need to change that formula.  In any event, the last week end date would always be CurrentWeekStart -1.  So, using `"<" & CurrentWeekStart` as the criteria for the last week end date, will work, so long as the Current Week Start formula is correct.